# Azure BlockBlob Upload From Stream always has content length 0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When I call "await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);", I find that stream has a content length of some value(500+ bytes).

But once the call is made, I see that there is no change in the blockblob.
I check it in fiddler and see the call made has a  Entity content-length =0.

Would appreciate if someone could please guide how to debug a problem like this.

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure you're setting the stream's position to 0. I've seen this error when you read something into the stream and then forget to set it's position to 0. Or you could share your code :).

Comment: I'm calling using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray))
                            {
                                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
                            }

Comment: Do I still need to set position to 0?

Comment: Yes you would still need to do this.

Comment: How many calls do you see in Fiddler? Does the URL have any query parameters? And which version of Azure Storage Client Library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The question was .. how to debug this?
I had same issue, found this helpful doc to get tracing enabled:

[Client-side Logging with the .NET Storage Client Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/client-side-logging-with-the-.net-storage-client-library#how-to-enable-storage-client-library-logging)

My issue was when uploading using UploadFromStreamAsync azure file storage while the destination resource already existed (an overwrite action), the fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) was needed. When uploading (and creating) new resources, the seek was not required.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting the bytearray, instead of uploading it directly?

Like this:

```
blob.UploadFromByteArray(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Count());
```